# Sharepoint 2010 installation preliminaries

Tags: sharepoint-2010

First of all sorry if this is a repost or is found to be duplicate.

I'm about to install sharepoint 2010 in my laptop for development.  I'm using a laptop with win 7 64-bit with 8GB RAM, with vs 2010 installed.

I'm having SP2010 with SP1 standard license.

Have went to lot of pre-requisite advisory pages but haven't got a satisfactory/complete answer and hence decided to pen down my doubts here.

Below are my queries

- Can i start by auto-running the CD (sorry if it sounds a lot stupid. kindly take note that i'm at beginning stage of SP2010 with VS programming background).
- Can i connect to sql server 2005 (32-bit) from sp2010 after installation for programming.  Is it possible technically.
- Should i need to install sql 2005/2008 (64-bit) before installing SP2010 or can i install it after completing installation of SP2010.

PLEASE provide pointers if any so that i can have a hiccup free, successful installation of sp2010.

**Edit:**

Have downloaded a bunch of files from the below url

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

Can anyone advise which virtual machine i should use to run the vhd image for sp2010

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing on Windows 7 is not recommended and tends to run into some incompatibilities. Can you use a virtual machine? [Here is a link which is useful for Win 7 installation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx)

Answering your questions:

1. You can install from the DVD or a mounted Image.
2. You can use SQL 2005 but only 64Bit.
3. You should install SQL server before installing SharePoint so it will be more automated

Comment: kravits- thanks:).  Can you advise me on where to get one. is it available at no or less cost?

Comment: Looks like you have downloaded some VHDs. I have never used these but you need a server which runs Hyper-V I think. Install guide [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/B/6/6B63BAC2-8CCF-4A45-9E4E-AA3BE0E735C7/Virtual%20Machine%20Setup%20Guide.docx). I would recommend just installing windows server 2008r2/2012, SQL server and sharepoint manually on Vm software like [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)(Free).